# Under which circumstances is the sum of $n$ $k$-th powers a $k$-th power?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Consider the sum $s$ of $n$ natural numbers each rised to a certain power $k$:

$$s= a_1^k + a_2^k + \cdots + a_n^k.$$

Under which circumstances is $s = b^k$, for some $b \in \mathbb N$?

Comment: considering that the special case $n=2$ proved quite problematic to solve, I don't think much can be said.. Interesting nonetheless ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [Waring-Hilbert theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring's_problem), every natural number $s$ is the sum of $g(k)$ $k$-th powers, i.e., $s=a_1^k+\cdots +a_{g(k)}^k$. So, if $n$ is big enough, every $s=b^k$ is the sum of $k$-th powers.
It is still an open problem to determine the numbers $g(k)$ (which are minimal with this property), e.g., $g(3)=9$, $g(4)=19$. For the presumed solution, see [here](http://oeis.org/A002804).

A more restricted version of the question is due to Euler, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture).

Comment: Oh, the theorem says that you need at least $9$ cubes. You can use more, but whether or not an integer $s$ is really the sum of $2001$ non-zero cubes, is another question (try it !).

Comment: I've tried, but with no results. Do you have any ideas about what to do to deal with this type of question?

Comment: Here is a solution: $13^3=4^3+4^3+4^3+2^3+1997\cdot 1^3$ is the sum of $2001$ nonzero cubes.